# I need to beep when I add a listbox item within my thread. It's in a thread and the thread subroutine will not let me do anything, but add the item

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I would like to add some data to a listbox and then play a sound (Beep). I tried the following code:

```
 Public Sub serverThread()
        '
        'Listen for data.
        '
        Dim udpclient As New UdpClient(8080)
        '
        While Me.Visible

            Dim remoteipendpoint As New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0)
            Dim receivebytes As Byte()
            '
            receivebytes = udpclient.Receive(remoteipendpoint)
            returndata = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivebytes)
            '
            ListBox1.Items.Add(remoteipendpoint.Address.ToString() + ":" + returndata.ToString())
            Beep()
        End While

        '
    End Sub
```

When execution gets to beep, it throws an exception saying something about cross threading and I can't do this while in the thread. I thought while I was in the thread subroutine I could do anything. Can you help?

Comment: Pop a [BackgroundWorker()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=netcore-3.1) in your form and place your infinite loop into the DoWork() handler.  When you want to update your GUI use the ReportProgess() method which will fire the ProgressChanged() event.  From that event you can safely update your GUI.

Comment: In my searches I discovered a call (Delegate). This seems simpler, even though I don't know how to use it. What about starting a second thread?

Comment: You should move `remoteipendpoint` to OUTSIDE the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go the "simplest" route, then just use `Invoke()` with an anonymous method whenever you want to update the GUI:

```
 Dim entry As String = remoteipendpoint.Address.ToString() + ":" + returndata.ToString()
 Me.Invoke(Sub()
               ListBox1.Items.Add(entry)
               Beep()
           End Sub)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the most elegant solution I have seen and the shortest. It works. You have my gratitude!